# I am trying to fetch pick list from salesforce using js force but i can't find any way to fetch that

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsforce

I am trying to fetch pick list from salesforce using js force but i can't find any way to fetch that

```
try{
  await sfConnection.login(
    config.salesForce.username,
    config.salesForce.password
  );
  const query = await sfConnection.conn.query(
    `SELECT VALID_COMPANY_PROOF__c FROM Account WHERE hed__Primary_Contact__c = '${id}'`
  );
  return query;
}catch(err){
  console.log(err);
}
```